# Question related to shifted parabola

Tags: conic-sections

I have problem in dealing the question related to the equation of shifted parabola. I have a question as

"A parabola whose latus rectum is $4c$, slide between two rectangular axes. Find the locus of focus and the equation of curve traced out by the parabola."

Answer (score 3):

Using standard form of the parabola: $(x,y)=(ct^{2},2ct)$, then the equation of the tangent at $[t]$ is

$$x-ty+ct^{2}=0 \quad \ldots \ldots (1) $$

If tangents at $[t]$ and $[t']$ are perpendicular,
$$tt'=-1$$

Then the equation of another tangent at $[t']$ is
$$x+\frac{y}{t}+\frac{c}{t^{2}}=0$$

That is
$$t^{2}x+ty+c=0 \quad \ldots \ldots (2) $$

The required locus is given by the perpendicular distances of the focus $(c,0)$ from the tangents:

\begin{align*}
  (X,Y) &=
  \left(
    \frac{c+0+ct^{2}}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}},
    \frac{t^{2}c+0+c}{\sqrt{t^{4}+t^{2}}}
  \right) \\
  &=
  \left(
    c\sqrt{1+t^{2}},
    \frac{c\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}{t}
  \right) \\
\end{align*}

Confine the sliding parabola in the first quadrant by taking $t>0$.

Considering $\dfrac{X}{Y}=t$ and eliminating $t$,  we have

$$\frac{1}{X^{2}}+\frac{1}{Y^{2}}=c^{2}$$

Alternatively, let $t=\tan \theta$,

$$(X,Y)=(c\sec \theta, c\csc \theta) $$